# Custom TabelView Cell Disappearing Cell Buttons On Scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using custom table cell in table view which consist of 2 labels and two buttons and 1 textfield and it work properly but the problem comes when i scroll table view up/down some of the buttons from top cell get disappeared and never come back...plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

In each scroll `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called by `UITableView` . Please check this function if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to solve your Problem. here `cell` is object of Your custom cell

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];


    if (cell) {
        cell=nil;
        [cell release];
        [cell removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Defeats the purpose of re-using cells.